# Mysql query to find "Not a friend"

Tags: mysql

### I want a mysql query which retrieve records list of users who are not friends of current user and friend request sent by current user to other users.

Here is how my `users` table (id, username)
Here is my `friends` table (id, friend_one, friend_two, status)

status 0 indicates pending request and 1 indicates request accepted. When request is accepted 1 update and insert query is fired. For example (1,4,1,0) 4 sends request to 1 and user 1 accepts the request now the entry in friends table will look like (1,4,1,1) (2,1,4,1).

> > users(1,'A')
> >
> > users(2,'B')
> >
> > users(3,'C')
> >
> > users(4,'D')
> >
> > users(5,'E')
> >
> > Friends table entry
> >
> > friends (1,4,1,1)
> >
> > friends (2,1,4,1)
> >
> > friends (3,1,2,0)
>
> friends (4,3,1,0)

Expected Result

> username id status
>
> B         2  0
>
> E        5  NULL

**EDIT**

This is what I am trying but I am also getting a record who have sent me a friend request which I dont want

```
SELECT u2.username, u2.id, f.status
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN users u2
ON u1.id != u2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN friends f
ON u1.id = f.friend_one
AND u2.id = f.friend_two
WHERE u1.id = 1
AND (f.status IS NULL
OR f.status = 0)
```

Comment: Use SQL's `NOT` to negative the condition to go from "a friend" to "not a friend".

Comment: But I also want list of users to whom current user has sent the friend request.

Comment: What have you tried?  Seems like you're just asking for us to write a query for you.

Comment: This is my query

`SELECT u2.username, u2.id, f.status FROM users u1 INNER JOIN users u2 ON u1.id != u2.id LEFT OUTER JOIN friends f ON (u1.id = f.friend_one AND u2.id = f.friend_two) OR (u1.id = f.friend_two AND u2.id = f.friend_one) WHERE u1.id = 1  AND (f.status IS NULL OR f.status = 0)`

Comment: @Manx_Warrior you can edit your question to add the query and make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand where you're going with this.. this answer should get you close.

```
select users.name, users.id, coalesce(friends.status, friends2.status) as status
from users
left join friends on friends.friend_two = 1 and friends.friend_one = users.id
left join friends friends2 on friends2.friend_two = users.id and friends2.friend_one = 1
where users.id != 1
and (friends.status is null or friends.status != 1)
and (friends2.status is null or friends2.status != 1)
```

Comment: Can you provide a JS fiddle for the above query

Comment: The output is perfect but I also want status along with username and ID how can I do that.